# Ubuntu 20.04 display scale not consistent between full screen and window mode in VM fusion

Tags: 20.04, vmware

After installing Ubuntu in VM fusion. I turned on "Use full screen retina display" in the virtual machine settings. This allows me to select 2k resolution in Ubuntu display settings. I also set the scale factor to 200% in full screen mode. However when I exit full screen mode the display goes back to 100% scale and 2k resolution. Does anyone know how to make scale factor setting consistent between full screen and window screen?